# Delay on Ajax or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Alright I'm wondering how to delay before redirecting using Ajax because I've included exit splash page.

This is the code :

```
setTimeout(5000);
window.location = "https://www.google.com"
```

I've also tried this :

```
setTimeout(function(){ document.location = 'http://www.google.com';}, 2000);
```

I've also tried :

```
delay : 3000
```

Splash Page javascript:

```
<!-- Start of ExitSplash.com Code -->
<script language="javascript">
var exitsplashmessage = '***************************************\n\n W A I T   B E F O R E   Y O U   G O !\n\n  CLICK THE *CANCEL* BUTTON RIGHT NOW\n     TO STAY ON THE CURRENT PAGE.\n\n I HAVE SOMETHING VERY SPECIAL FOR YOU!\n\n***************************************';
var exitsplashpage = 'http://www.facebook.com';
</script>
<script language="javascript" src="http://www.google/bonus/exitsplash.php?tc=3399cc&uh=none&ad=none&sh=no&hv=no&bh=22&fs=12&lf=Arial&at=Powered%20by%20ExitSplash"></script>
<!-- End of ExitSplash.com Code -->
```

Comment: And what is the problem with `setTimeout(function(){ document.location = 'http://www.google.com';}, 2000);`?

Comment: @Regent , the javascript of the splash page will be executed before the delays ends.

Answer (score 0):

hope it will help you.

```
setTimeout(functionName(),5000);

function functionName()
{
document.location = 'http://www.google.com';
}
```

Comment: Sadly my iframe functions before the redirect function doesn't work.
Any other method?

Comment: It has to be `setTimeout(functionName, 5000);` and then it will be just the same code as in question.

Comment: Well , this worked but it kept on triggering my other javascript function at the bottom of the page..
Any other way so i can prevent the function from triggering??
I'll upload the javascript function in the top.

Comment: @JaySuriyaa `setTimeout(functionName(),5000);` will execute function without any delays.

Comment: @Regent, is there any way that it will trigger it after the delays?

Comment: @JaySuriyaa I have already said above: `setTimeout(functionName, 5000);`. **But** it is just the same as your original `setTimeout(function(){ document.location = 'http://www.google.com';}, 2000);` (well, 5000ms instead of 2000ms, but it doesn't matter), and I don't see any reasons why your code doesn't work.

Comment: @Regent, I've added another javascript function..By the time the page got redirected , the javascript will be triggered out of nowhere .. so it will redirect them to another page..

Answer (score 0):

try it.

```
setTimeout(function(){document.location.href="http://www.google.com";}, 3000);
```

Comment: From [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.location): _you can work with document.location as if it were a string in most cases: document.location = 'http://www.example.com' is a synonym of document.location.href = 'http://www.example.com'._

Comment: I kept on still having the pop appeared before the page gets redirect.

Comment: please create fiddle.